# django IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed with get_or_create

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I've been working to a django project for 2 moths, but now it gives me this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /exams/26
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 916, in get_or_create
return self.get(**kwargs), False
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in get
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
exams.models.Exam.DoesNotExist: Exam matching query does not exist.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 313, in _commit
return self.connection.commit()
sqlite3.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\exams\views.py", line 47, in f
createExam(nome=getExam(),anno=getAnno(),semestre=getSemestre(),facoltà=None)
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\exams\views.py", line 19, in createExam
Exam.objects.get_or_create(nome=nome[i],anno=anno[i],semestre=semestre[i], 
Facoltà=Facoltà.objects.get(id=27))
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 921, in get_or_create
with transaction.atomic(using=self.db):
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 263, in __exit__
connection.commit()
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 337, in commit
self._commit()
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 312, in _commit
with debug_transaction(self, "COMMIT"), self.wrap_database_errors:
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 91, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\doniy\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 313, in _commit
return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

What i wanna do is create many instaces of Exam model, that has a Foreign Key of Facoltà model, with the get_or_create method. Unfortunately i can't do it due to this problem. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def f(request, id):
    facoltà = Facoltà.objects.get(id=id)
    global countF
    if countF == 0:
        connectToEsse3Page(getCod(facoltà))
        countF += 1
    createExam(nome=getExam(),anno=getAnno(),semestre=getSemestre(),facoltà=facoltà)
    exam = Exam.objects.all()
    context = {
        "facoltà":facoltà,
        "exam": exam,
    }
    return render(request, "exams/facoltà.html",context=context)


def createExam(nome,anno,semestre,facoltà):
    for i in range(len(nome)):
    Exam.objects.get_or_create(nome=nome[i],anno=anno[i],semestre=semestre[i], Facoltà=facoltà)
```

models.py:

```
class Facoltà(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['nome'], name='unique_migration_nome'
            )
        ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Exam(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    anno = models.IntegerField(choices=ANNI)
    semestre = models.IntegerField(choices=SEMESTRI)
    Facoltà = models.ForeignKey(Facoltà, on_delete=models.CASCADE)



    def show_period(self):
        ret = ''

        for nome in ANNI:
            if (nome[0] == self.anno):
                ret += nome[1] + ' '

        for nome in SEMESTRI:
            if (nome[0] == self.semestre):
                ret += nome[1]

        return ret

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

The problem is in the line get_or_create, but i don't know why. It seems all correct for me. Can anyone see where do i get wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried to create an exam in the admin page and it still gives me this error. Maybe it's a model problem, i wrote something wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found out the problem.

Long story short: **Never name an attribute like a class!!!**

I gave the name "Facoltà" to the Exam's attribute (the Foreign Key), the same of the class. Sorry for my carelessness XD